# Is it possible to reload the view without restarting Django?

Tags: django, django-views

After changing the view function without runserver again, and press F5 to refresh the page, Django will not reload the new view but use the previous one. but if you change the template, Django always uses the new one.

So, Is there a way to make Django reload the view every time the user refresh the page, I think that is very convenient for develop to modify the view function frequently.

Comment: With the development server, python code changes generally restart the server automatically. With a template, it's always just reading the file so that's a different story.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you running your Django site without runserver? Does this mean you're running it via another method? Runserver should pick up changes to any python file that's used by the project, it'll take a few seconds though.

Comment: I run it via pydev, it doesn't reload the change code. so each time I changed the view function, I have to runserver again to reload the changed code. that makes programming slowly.

Answer (score 9):

If you are running django using the dev server (./manage.py runserver) then it will always reload when it detects any code changes. This is even more efficient than reloading with every request. If you make a change, it reloads when it needs to.

If you are running a production server (nginx, apache, etc) and you want code-reload, then you need to add something to your wsgi module to detect code changes.

Code reloading with apache: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Code reloading with uwsgi: http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/TipsAndTricks

Comment: I use eclipse + pydev to develop.and Just use eclipse to runserver, and I found that it didn't reload the view function, but reload the template file, so each time I change the code, I have to restart it. is there any setting in the setting.py to enable it?

Comment: It's an issue with PyDev. As far as I'm aware there isn't a way to make it do the reloading (this may have changed since I last used it), I've always ended up running runserver through the terminal instead.

Comment: Yea regardless of what IDE I use, I always run the runserver in a terminal.

Comment: Yes, you guys inspired me, It is an issue in pydev.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Django as a WSGI application in daemon mode you just need to touch the `wsgi.py` for your site and it will reload the application next time there is a request. (So no need for any special options).

Comment: This may not have answer the original question but it answered my question!

Comment: Thanks +1, touch wsgi.py helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It is a known issue with PyDev. I would suggest running the server from terminal/cmd.
cd to your project directory where manage.py is present and run the server using

```
python manage.py runserver
```

You don't need to run the project from eclipse menu.
Any changes made in eclipse would be reflected as soon as they are made.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed it is a setting in pyDev run configurations. I wonder why but it seems --noreload is configured by default. So I edit arguments of run settings and now the server is reloading also when editing views.

Comment: --noreload is put by default since the way it implements reloading can cause problems with breakpoints and debugging

Answer (score 0):

Try using gunicorn or nginx as running server... They dont restart on code change
try typing

`gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 app.wsgi:application`